# Comparing numbers in asp.net

Tags: c#

I am creating a random number generator, when a certain number is generated I want the label to change change colour.

```
Random RandomClass = new Random ();

Num1.Text = RandomClass.Next (1, 49).ToString();

if (Num1.Text >= "9") 
{
   this.Num1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkBlue;
}
```

Now I know `>= "9"` Doesn't work but I can't seem to think of anything else.

Comment: What do you mean `doesn't work`? Are you sure you want to try _integer comparasion_ instead of _string comparasion_?

Comment: I want to compare what the RandomClass.Next generates and if it is a certain range of numbers change the background colour of the labels.

Answer (score 0):

Emm, I guess this will do it:

```
int r = RandomClass.Next (1, 49);
Num1.Text = r.ToString();

if (r >= 9) 
{
   this.Num1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkBlue;
}
```

Comment: Since [`Random.Next(int, int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx) returns `Int32`, there is no point to store it as a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

*Well*, it is not clear what you actually want to but what you do is *string comparasion* not *integer comparasion*.

If you want to compare int values, you can do it like;

```
Random RandomClass = new Random ();
int i = RandomClass.Next (1, 49);
Num1.Text = i.ToString();

if (i >= 9) 
{
   this.Num1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkBlue;
}
```

Comment: Every number it generates has the background colour attached.